# What is the default value of the iterationCount property of Rfc2898DeriveBytes class

Tags: c#, .net, default-value

I'm trying to implement an AES algorithm as PHP by examining a sample C# code. But i could not find the default value of the iterationCount property of Rfc2898DeriveBytes class after running this constructor :

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes k2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd1, salt1);
```

constructor definition is:

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes(String, Int32)
```

and all i have found is that : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bah3ekk(v=vs.100).aspx

Could you please help me to learn what it is?

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rfc2898derivebytes.cs,46

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default is [1000](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rfc2898derivebytes.cs,84) as per the source code.

In addition, the minimum recommended number of iterations is 1000.

> Iteration count is the number of times an operation is performed. For this method, the count should be greater than zero. The minimum recommended number of iterations is 1000.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.iterationcount(v=vs.110).aspx)

The same source also contains a commented code example which answers the question even more directly.

Comment: I want to increase the count of iterations because we are doing fortify scan on this code snippet, can you please suggest me like how to increase the count.
here is my current code snippet 
`var pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x79, 0x96, 0x81, 0x9e, 0x80, 0x8d, 0x95, 0x84, 0x96, 0x95, 0x84, 0x95, 0x96 });` 
I am getting following message `Weak Cryptographic Hash: Insecure PBE Iteration Count`.

Comment: There's an overload which takes a 3rd parameter which is the iteration count, e.g: `Rfc2898DeriveBytes(String, Byte[], Int32)`